# Sides of extrusion are not showing

Tags: mesh, extrude

The sides are invisible when extruding a png images exept part of the logo who touch the image border. Any idea why it dose that? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have imported your logo with *Add Image > Image as Planes*, so what you show is an image projected on a plane, it is just a quad mesh, not a logo converted to mesh with all the contour converted to vertices, when you extrude you're just extruding a plane and it makes a cube. Note that the front face keeps the texture:

[image]

What you can do is convert your logo to a svg in an image editor like Illustrator or Inkscape, then import it into Blender, then convert your svg to mesh. You can do the whole thing is Blender but it's a bit more complicated:

[image]